# Dropdown selected value with ADO data model and ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Having a hard time getting the selected value to stick on an ASP.NET MVC page.

```
public partial class AdjustedCost
{
    public SelectList BrandList { get; set; }

    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

The BrandList is getting set in the controller:

```
    private static SelectList BrandList = new SelectList( new[] { "Brand1","Brand2","Brand3" } );

    public ActionResult EditByTextbox(String textBoxEdit)
    {
        ...
        AjustedCost xadjcost = db.xAdjCost.First(e => e.InvtId == textBoxEdit);

        ...
        xadjcost.BrandList = BrandList;

        return View( "Edit", xadjcost);
    }
```

And in the Edit view:

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Brand, Model.BrandList )
```

Is this correct? The dropdown portion is working but the selected value is just returning the top of the list, not the actual currently set value.

Comment: What is xAdjCost? Is that the same as AdjustedCost class or is that a different model? If they are the same does your Brand property contain one of the values from SelectList (Brand1, Brand2, Brand3)??? Did you check what your drop down list renders for select item values?

Another thing to check is whether or not you have any ViewBag or ViewData values that are named Brand. If that is the case they will both go into FormCollection and overwrite each other. Basically you cannot name a viewbag or viewdata with the same name as one of the model properties!!!

Comment: Same! Sorry, renamed them in code to make it more readable and ended up making it less.

Comment: Thanks for the input, will look into seeing if they're sharing names. I'm new to MVC and am quite amazed with the level of opaqueness; at least to the new user.

Comment: You might also want to look at the case of your values. I'm not sure if the model binder will match brand1 to Brand1. I usually work with keys - integers when I use drop down lists... But problem that is the hardest to catch is if you have a ViewBag.Brand defined somewhere in your code. This will cause the drop down list to not select the proper value.

Comment: You are setting `xadjcost.Brand` somewhere in the controller, correct?  It's not in your example code.

Comment: @JasonBerkan: This is being set automatically by ADO/entityframework I believe. All of the other textbox fields are being populated correctly.

Comment: You believe, but do you know?  What does the debugger show?  I'm concerned that in your example, Brand appears to be in a partial class  that you have written.  Thus assigning the object via an EF .First() call may not fill in Brand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in selectedValue into the constructor of SelectList(), instead of using that static variable, which has no context to your current value from the DB.

Therefore I would create a method to give you your select list in context of the value you need selected i.e.

```
private SelectList BrandList(string selectedValue)
{
    SelectList selectList = null;
    List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = null;

    try
    {
        selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Brand1", Value = "Brand1" });
        selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Brand2", Value = "Brand2" });
        selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Brand3", Value = "Brand3" });
        selectList = new SelectList(selectListItems, "Value", "Text", selectedValue);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        exception.Log(); // or whatever you do with your exceptions
    }

    return selectList;
}
```

Therefore in your action result, this:

```
xadjcost.BrandList = BrandList;
```

Becomes:

```
xadjcost.BrandList = BrandList(whateverTheBrandValueFromYourDbIs);
```

Comment: Gave a +1 for a great, honest effort. Unfortunately this doesn't work, either. I have a feeling it's hanging up on something with ADO.NET

Comment: We'll get there. This code *should* work. So to confirm your issue: when the form is rendered to screen, the selected value is not being selected? If so, have you debugged to ensure that the brand value is making it into the model inside both the controller and the view? Are you also sure that there is a precise match from the DB value to the select item options?

Comment: The selected value is making it all the way to the razor template file. When I expand the SelectList, it shows a selected item. The precise match issue may be it. I've had issues in the past with string comparisons and C#. Kind of why I think it's a ADO issue, could be it's not doing the comparison as expected.

Comment: Okay, so your problem now is that the select box is only showing the selected item once you expand the box to show the options?

Comment: Yes. It's always showed all of the items(Brand1, Brand2, Brand3). The problem is that the selected value doesn't show the current Brand. For example, AdjustedCost item has a Brand of Brand2 but the selected item is shown as Brand1. Which is odd because in the template during debugging it shows the selected item as Brand2.

Comment: Two things I would check in your position: 1. that the strings precisely match; 2. that no javascript/jquery is interfering with the dropdown.